# Python Mock patch.multiple argument names

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

It's possible to change the test argument name of a patched class or function when using patch as a decorator.

```
@patch('module.ClassName2')
@patch('module.ClassName1')
def test(MockClass1, MockClass2):
    MockClass1.test.return_value = 'testing'
```

However, I can't seem to find in the documentation how to differentiate the original object and the mock when using `patch.multiple`.

```
@patch.multiple('module.ClassName', foo=DEFAULT, bar=DEFAULT)
def test(foo, bar):
    foo.return_value = 'foo'
```

In the above example, the arguments in the test must be `foo` and `bar`. Is there any clean way to allow their use with a clearer differentiation, e.g. `mock_foo`?

This would also be handy in cases where the original class or method is needed in part of the test, avoiding imports like `from module import Class as OriginalClass`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No and ... yes:

- No because if you take a look to [`mock` source code](http://code.google.com/p/mock/source/browse/mock.py#1496) you will see that there is no way to change `attribute_name`
- Yes because they are passed as keyword args and so they are embedded in keywords args dictionary: so you can extract them from dictionary as you want.

Follow a simple example of how you can do it... I know that maybe was not exactly what you are looking for but it is the only way to do it.

```
@patch.multiple('module.ClassName', foo=DEFAULT, bar=DEFAULT)
def test(**mocks):
    mock_foo, mock_bar = mocks["foo"], mocks["bar"]
    mock_foo.return_value = 'foo'
    mock_bar.return_value = 'bar'
```

If you use `patch.multiple` as context manager that is the only way to get the mocks, so the two way are consistent

```
def test():
    with patch.multiple('module.ClassName', foo=DEFAULT, bar=DEFAULT) as mocks:
        mock_foo, mock_bar = mocks["foo"], mocks["bar"]
        mock_foo.return_value = 'foo'
        mock_bar.return_value = 'bar'
```

Comment: I was aware that the mocks were passed as a dictionary in the context manager, but didn't think to apply the same logic to the decorator! I think you're right, and this is as close as I can get. Thanks!

Comment: is it possible to give each mock a specific name and not rely on the relative ordering of the input to the function to determine the naming?